# Installing pyqwt on Mavericks

Tags: ros, homebrew, mavericks, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've noticed several threads where people have claimed to have built ROS on OSX Mavericks, I'm currently unable to install pyqwt via homebrew, basically hitting this same error that has been reported but not solved: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/25224

I've tried reinstalling both qt and sip to no avail.

Any helpful hints?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/112856/installing-pyqwt-on-mavericks/) by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13902 on 2013-12-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on 2013-12-24**:
Are you using default Python?

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-12-25**:
Yes, using default Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The current release version of PyQt (4.10.3) has some issues with libc++/clang build settings necessary for Mavericks. Basically PyQt incorrectly parses the QMake build settings that were used to build Qt, resulting in incorrect build flags being generated for PyQt interoperable projects. There is a fix proposed for homebrew here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/25225 and for PyQt here: http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2013-December/033537.html

```
brew install https://raw.github.com/jensenb/homebrew/76e8bf65dccdeeb785ca2f296ac2458460ba2fde/Library/Formula/pyqt.rb
```

---

Originally posted by [jensenb](https://answers.ros.org/users/4449/jensenb/) with karma: 316 on 2013-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-12-25**:
Thanks -- that works for me.